# My code is taking a lot of time due to scanf function and after that it is not even running

Tags: c

My scanf function is not working in VS code...I've tried different things like uninstalling Antivirus and rebooting it but it's not working. Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int num;
  printf("Enter the number \n");
  scanf("%d");

  printf("Divisibility test returns %d\n", num % 97);

  return 0;
}
```

It is taking a lot of time and it still is not running:(

Comment: `scanf("%d", &num);`?

Comment: scanf("%d"); how can scanf know where to store the scanned value?

Comment: reading the documentation is very helpful if a function is not behaving as expected

Comment: @Kartik9000, you [asked this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364903/my-scanf-function-is-not-working-in-vs-code-what-should-i-do), and we answered it, and you deleted it.  Why are you asking the same question again?  Why are you wasting our time?

Comment: If you decide you want to re-ask a question which you previously deleted, the correct course of action is to undelete the original question (there's a button for that), not to post a new one.

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm sorry I'm new to this website...I was unable to see your answers...I just found out that I can see your answers in the comments

Comment: @Zoso aaah okay...thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `scanf()` where it should store the read value. It's done by passing a *pointer* to the destination variable as an parameter.

```
 scanf("%d", &num);
```

---

**EDIT**

It's worth checking the return value of `scanf`. It returns a number of successfully parsed argument. The value of `1` is expected:

```
if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
  fputs("Failed to parse a number\n", stderr);
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Also worth checking the return value from `scanf`